# Weird react behavior w.r.t. propTypes definition

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I just observed a weird behavior in `react` and wanted to check if it is a bug or expected behavior.

This is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/12bmacby/) where a React component is passed as a child prop and the propType is defined as a `React.PropTypes.function.isRequired`. In this case, the text in the child component "I am Child!" is not seen in the div in the result section.

This is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/55udj9uv/) with exact same code as above but with the `propTypes` definition removed. Here, the text is shown as expected.

I am not sure how does the definition of `propTypes` changes the render output of the component. If you know why this may be happening, please share your thoughts.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isRequired' of undefined` is printed over your console because it's `React.PropTypes.func.isRequired` and not `React.PropTypes.function.isRequired`. Always check the console errors when you see unexpected behavior. Your code simply has a typo.

Comment: @ivarni Thanks for the explanation. Don't know why I missed it.